# Issue with the layout design with putting ribbon on the layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, xml-layout

This is the requirement to design layout like the below image:

[image]

**I have developed all the widgets except the red ribbon TextView.** So I just want a idea to put the red ribbon textview in the layout. As you can see the ribbon is full width where the white background is with some margin. So can anyone tell me to design this red ribbon textview.

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions for this question is appreciated.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Also, what sort of image resources do you have for that ribbon, i.e. do you need to draw it in code or just refer to images?

Comment: I have total three images only.. one is box, red ribbon and bottom logo image..background are developed using drawable xml files.

Comment: hi for that u have to use image view not text-view and for that simple add image background and that box make image with padding simple

Comment: @Rahul: Its not simple as you are thinking..

Comment: Use Button. set background image and text